# Editing a batch file to take argument directly from the code

Tags: date, batch-file

I have a batch file that return date minus number of given days.

E.g. : if we are 09/11/2013 `batch.bat today -1`  will return 08/11/2013

and if it's a weekend it will return the Friday date.

The problem is that I try to make the batch give me the last business day without entering any argument but I failed

Here is the code :

```
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
echo to get yesterdays date use     call "%~n0" today -1
echo.
echo Add a third parameter if you want a separator in the date string
echo EG: for this format YYYY-MM-DD using yesterdays date
echo     call "%~n0" today -1 -
echo.
pause
goto :EOF)

set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set "YY=%result:~0,4%" & set "MM=%result:~4,2%" & set "DD=%result:~6,2%" & set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
:: if the daynum is a weekend then run the batch file again to get the friday
set "weekend="
if %daynum% EQU 1 set /a weekend=qty - 2
if %daynum% EQU 7 set /a weekend=qty - 1
if defined weekend %0 %1 %weekend%

set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
echo %%YY%% is set to %YY%
echo %%MM%% is set to %MM%
echo %%DD%% is set to %DD%
echo.
echo daynum is "%daynum%"
echo date is %YY%%MM%%DD%
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for here.  Are you asking how to make the second parameter optional?  Have you tried to make the change you are asking for?  How is it failing?

Comment: I want make the 2 parameters hard-coded

Comment: Then you should probably modify the first `if` statement to do what you want rather than terminate the script.  
Have you tried to make the change you are asking for? How is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set qty=-1
:loop4weekends
set "separator="
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,now)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set "YY=%result:~0,4%" & set "MM=%result:~4,2%" & set "DD=%result:~6,2%" & set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
:: if the daynum is a weekend then loop to get the friday
set "weekend="
if %daynum% EQU 1 set weekend=1&set "qty=-3"
if %daynum% EQU 7 set weekend=1&set "qty=-2"
if defined weekend goto :loop4weekends

set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
```